# rake task to perform bundle install in another project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bash, rake, bundle

How can I write a rake task to run a bundle install in a different project? I have create a project with just rake, and written tasks like this

```
task :bundle do
  projects.each do |name, repo|
    if Dir.exists?("../#{name}")
      exec("cd ../#{name} && bin/bundle install")
    end
  end
end
```

But when I run this I get:

```
Using rake 10.3.2
Using bundler 1.9.6
Bundle complete! 1 Gemfile dependency, 2 gems now installed.
Use `bundle show [gemname]` to see where a bundled gem is installed.
```

Which looks ok at first, but is in fact the `bundle install` for the current rake-only project and not the target rails project.

I also tried back ticks

```
puts `cd ../#{name} && bin/bundle install`
```

But it did the same. I also tried just `bundle install` instead of `bin/bundle install`, but it didn't work.

When I run it on the command like directly it does what I expect:

```
Using rake 10.4.2
Using CFPropertyList 2.3.1
...
...
Using turbolinks 2.5.3
Using uglifier 2.7.1
Bundle complete! 34 Gemfile dependencies, 120 gems now installed.
Use `bundle show [gemname]` to see where a bundled gem is installed.
```

How do I get it to do the right `bundle install` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Couple of things to note on this**

`bin/bundle` will only work if the `bundle` files exists in in `bin` directory

- there are number of different methods to execute commands in a shell

  - `exec('echo "Hello World"')` - runs the command and replaces the current process with it.
  - `system('echo "Hello World"')` - runs the command in a subshell and captures the exit status code
  - `` `echo "hello world"` `` - runs the command in a subshell and captures all output to the STDOUT and STDERR but not the exit status code.

**To the why it didn't work**

You need to provide bundler with a clean environment so it knows that you are bundling a different project. surround the commands within your rake task with `Bundler.with_clean_env` block as per below

```
task :bundle do
  Bundler.with_clean_env do
    projects.each do |name, repo|
      if Dir.exists?("../#{name}")
        exec("cd ../#{name} && bundle install")
      end
    end
  end
end
```